# artifactory release build can't commit in svn

Tags: svn, jenkins, commit, release

i try to build my project in jenkins using the artifactory release plugin, and this what i get as error :

```
[RELEASE] Creating subversion tag: svn://server/services/services-jenkins/tags/testArtiRel/services-jenkins-0.0.10
Failure in post build SCM action: Subversion tag creation failed: svn: E170001: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: E170001: Authentication required for '5e5fe3c8-5dc8-f042-9746-0486f904d5e5'
Started calculate disk usage of build
Finished Calculation of disk usage of build in 0 seconds
Started calculate disk usage of workspace
Finished Calculation of disk usage of workspace in  3 second
[RELEASE] You are using an old subversion jenkins plugin, please consider upgrading.
[RELEASE] Reverting working copy: /usr/share/tomcat7/.jenkins/jobs/services-jenkins/workspace/services-jenkins
Finished: FAILURE
```

i see that the plugin couldn't commit in svn tag ! but the svn login i used is correct !

Comment: There is a note in the error that says **"You are using an old subversion jenkins plugin, please consider upgrading."**

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when I tried to release a Maven project with the Jenkins Maven plugin.

This plugin is trying to create a tag from the local workspace. Tt failed because the SVN layout version of the workspace is different compare to the SVN client version.

In my case, the SVN layout is 1.6 and my client is 1.7.

To solve my issue, I've installed a SVN 1.6 client on the machine, and I was able to release my project.

The SVN layout of your workspace is managed by Jenkins in the global options.